# How can I login into web application with SAML using system credentials in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

once I click on URL of web application it needs to authenticate using my system credential and login into the web app.
Trying to achieve it in spring boot using SAML.

Answer (score 1):

Very broad question this. Not a concrete answer , though this has some useful links .
This is a classic IdP / SP scenario where you have to login based on logged in users. The scope to explain this itself is quite broad , but there are some really good examples to get this done. A couple of bookmarked links that we had used for these are the following. Spring security has specific modules for SAML2 and configuration with the right interceptors and configuration this should not be too hard

https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample
https://github.com/isaacgarza/saml-example
https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/10/14/spring-security-saml-database-authentication

Comment: thanks..let me go through the links and start implementing

Comment: Good references Bhai;)